# Get state.filters Array from other outside component using react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table-v7

Hi Im trying to implement react-table filtering feature using this sample.https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/filtering. But I have a question. I have created a different component and I call my react-table component  inside of its. I mean my main component is wrapping table component. Is there any way to obtain state.filters array in react-table component ? Could you help me at this issue ?

my main component :

....

```
import React from 'react'
import DataTable from '../dataTable/Datagrid'; --> imported react-table example different file as component

function List() {

// state management
// I want to call state.filters here to use set for any state

    return (
        <div>
            <DataTable
                            columns={columns}
                            data={ playerState.items}
                            </>
        </div>
    )
}

export default List
```

...

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation **React Table is a collection of hooks for building powerful tables and datagrid experiences. These hooks are lightweight, composable, and ultra-extensible, but do not render any markup or styles for you.**

So you need to use the useEffect hook to listen to changes in the state and then invoke a function prop passed down from the List component to the table. This function can then set the Filter using the useState Hooks as follows.
**// list component**

```
 function List() {
   const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState([])
   function getFilter(filteredValue) {
      setFilter(filteredValue)
   }
   
   return (
      <div>
        <DataTable
                columns={columns}
                data={ playerState.items}
                filter={getFilter}
        </>
      </div>
   )
 }
```

Inside your
**'../dataTable/Datagrid'**
You need to create useEffect Hook that listens to filtered data and then you can call the function getFilter passing the filtered data as the argument this will then update the filter state upon every update of the filtered data

```
function Datagrid({filter}) {
  // use Effect Here
   useEffect(() => {
     filter(state.filter);
   }, [state]);

}
```

Comment: No. It doesn't work. I tried an example like this.

Comment: My laptop is dead now, I would have shared the codependency link

Comment: Please check out this https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-bird-yt1tx?file=/src/App.js